# Base class for IWebElement on Selenium .NET driver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium WebDriver with C#.

**All I want to do is figure out what the base class for `IWebElement` is.**

I can't find it anywhere online. Can anyone here help me figure it out?

I am starting to implement the PageObject design pattern. I have a PageObject called `Grid` that I want to be treated as an `IWebElement`, so it can do things like `.Click()`, .`GetAttribute()`, and `.SendKeys()`. When I do:

```
public class Grid : IWebElement
{
}
```

It forces me to implement all of the methods in `IWebElement`, but all I want them to do is default to their already implemented behavior.

I figured the way to achieve this would be to find the base class that `IWebElement` extends from, and have grid extend from **that**, but I cannot find it anywhere.

If anyone could help, **or** tell me a different way to achieve my goal of having `Grid` be treated as an `IWebElement`, I would very much appreciate it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `IWebElement` is an interface. Thus, it can't have a base class...

Comment: So how do i do what I'm trying to??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*OP said*:

> All I want to do is figure out what the base class for IWebElement is.

First of all, `IWebElement` is an interface so there's no base class for it.

Basically, you're looking for default `IWebElement` implementation: `RemoteWebElement`.

Check its source code [on GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebElement.cs).

Furthermore, `RemoteWebElement` is the base class of browser vendor-specialized implementations. For example, there's a [`FirefoxWebElement`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Firefox/FirefoxWebElement.cs).

### Update

OP said in some comment:

> I guess I should have rephrased. All I want to do is have Grid class
>   extend the funtionality of IWebElement, and be able to be treated as
>   an IWebElement. –

IMHO, you'll be more efficient if you provide such customization using [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) instead of inheritance. If you go with the inheritance approach you'll need to derive from all vendor-specific `RemoteWebElement` classes to provide your customization to all Web browsers supported by Selenium.

Summary. Why don't you implement your goal using [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)?

```
public static class GridWebElementExtensions 
{
      public static IWebElement Whatever(this IWebElement element)
      {
          // Do stuff here
      }
}
```

Going this way you'll extend any `IWebElement` implementation and your customizations will be available to all browsers!

Comment: So, if I make Grid extend RemoteWebElement, then my mission will be accomplished?

Comment: I guess I should have rephrased. All I want to do is have Grid class extend the funtionality of IWebElement, and be able to be treated as an IWebElement.

Comment: @kdeez BTW, if you want to support multiple browsers, you'll need to provide a derived class of vendor-specific `RemoteWebElement` classes: `FirefoxWebElement`, `ChromeWebElement`...

Comment: @kdeez Let me suggest you another approach (I'm going to improve my answer...).

Comment: I tried making it extend RemoteWebElement, but when I call PageFactory.InitElements() for the class containing the grid reference, it still complains that it's not an IWebElement.

Comment: I'll look into this implementation. Thank you for the help and for your responses!

Comment: @kdeez no problem! I believe you should go with the extension methods approach... In fact, Selenium provides official extendended functionality to `IWebElement` as extension methods.